# Problem with form_for Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, action

I have the following form_for declaration in a Rails site I am building:

```
form_for(form_question, :url => { :controller => "form_questions", :action => "edit", :id => form_question.id }) do |f|
```

but the site renders;

```
<form action="/form_questions/1/edit">
```

why is it putting the '/1/' before the "edit" in the action url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple Answer. [RESTful routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html).

Basically you have defined `resources  :form_questions` in config/routes.rb and that is transforming, automagically, your URL to make it RESTful.

Comment: apparently if i rename the action to "update" it works, go figure.

Comment: yep... `update` becomes a PUT request and it will generate a url of `/form_questions/:id`

Comment: Ahh, I get it - I didn't realise that Rails automatically changes the verb of the request based on the method.  That explains why 'new' is always posted.  lol I feel so stupid.  But that's really neat!

Comment: The other aspect is that, assuming the RESTful approach and using scaffolding, the you make a GET request to the edit action which retrieves the item in a form, the form is then PUT to the update action which writes to in the database. There is a similar relationship between new and create, you GET an the new action which returns a blank form and the form is POSTed to the create action to be written to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the RESTful helpers provided to you, like:

```
<% form_for(@form_question) do %>
  <%= f.text_field :question %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Which will generate a URL to either `create` or `update` depending on if the `@form_question` response to `new_record?` is `true` or `false` respectively. It'll also do other things, like give the form tag a different id attribute based also off what `new_record?` returns.

Comment: Yes I am doing this elsewhere, but in this particular case, I am unable to use the @form_question - as its actually looping through a set of records, so this option doesn't really apply.  Thanks for the answer though, you've inadvertently answered another question I had about how Rails seems to magically know the difference between create and edit.